# Fit G inside SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

Hi i have a group of path which is inside an svg. However when i change to size of the SVG the path remains outside of it can sm1 pls help me make the path size dynamic so it will always fit inside the svg ?

```
  <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" x="83.900307" y="307.898926" width="36" height="36">
    <g fill="#000000" stroke="none" style="" class="SmokeDetector dormant" onclick="elementClick()" id="r106Sensor1">
      <path d="M2130 4606 c-536 -69 -1002 -292 -1368 -655 -362 -359 -581 -791
 -659 -1301 -24 -157 -23 -472 1 -630 79 -519 298 -945 672 -1311 818 -798
2102 -880 3025 -192 119 88 316 277 406 388 148 183 298 445 373 652 160 441
179 943 54 1388 -219 776 -848 1392 -1628 1596 -207 54 -333 70 -561 74 -138
3 -246 0 -315 -9z m635 -111 c233 -43 428 -106 620 -200 693 -341 1154 -1003
1225 -1760 37 -398 -35 -784 -215 -1150 -116 -236 -238 -406 -423 -589 -190
 -188 -343 -296 -587 -417 -320 -157 -628 -229 -985 -229 -698 0 -1341 314
 -1765 862 -587 758 -607 1805 -50 2583 368 514 933 842 1585 919 89 10 508 -3
595 -19z" style=""></path>
    <path d="M2225 4280 c-136 -24 -216 -46 -283 -77 -234 -110 -451 -290 -583
 -485 -63 -92 -137 -255 -166 -365 -22 -85 -26 -119 -27 -258 -1 -156 0 -162
27 -217 31 -63 62 -88 118 -95 91 -13 226 99 356 295 125 187 216 251 343 239
72 -6 143 -43 201 -104 88 -92 123 -185 121 -318 -1 -102 -31 -206 -116 -404
 -139 -323 -187 -542 -186 -854 0 -264 45 -476 145 -678 60 -122 116 -201 214
 -302 145 -150 282 -227 402 -227 104 0 158 37 166 113 6 51 -10 87 -87 192
 -100 136 -186 342 -231 555 -19 89 -23 135 -23 300 0 178 3 203 26 291 14 52
45 133 68 178 44 89 74 122 273 304 293 269 497 603 561 919 20 97 20 281 1
373 -24 112 -86 227 -169 310 -168 168 -381 276 -631 319 -125 22 -388 20
 -520 -4z" style=""></path>
  </g>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Your `viewBox` is too small – it needs to match the elements bounding box. Otherwise, the image gets cropped. Use `getBBox()` to retrieve suitable values - e.g `viewBox="85.5 51.0 4630.1 4565.1" `

Comment: hi @herrstrietzel thanks a lot for that ! i would like for the inner path to be within the 36 x 36 svg element not the other way around im sorry if i didnt specify that.. could you please help me achieve this ?

Comment: Sorry but you're missing the point: once your viewBox is correct you can scale your svg to any layout size like 36x36px. In other words: the viewBox is not your layout size (think of it as your artboard). See this [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/XWxrwgj). Sure you can also scale the actual elements, but it's more complicated and usually not necessary.

Comment: @herrstrietzel OMG that makes so much sense ! and it worked ! thank you so very much ! im a bit of a noob when it comes to front end, turns out SVGs are a completly different ballgame ! would you mind adding it as an answer so i can accept it ?

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, your question was closed (imho way to quickly). Never mind. I highly recommend reading this [css-tricks tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/6-common-svg-fails-and-how-to-fix-them/) explaing some common svg misconceptions

Comment: will def give it a reading ! thanks a lot !

Comment: hi @herrstrietzel seems like stack reopened the question ! would you mind adding it as an answer ? i would love to accept it